# How to get the database error when executing SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have these statements:

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("some query", "some db connection");
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How do I get the messages from the database when this query is executed?

For example if 2 rows are affected, I want the SQL Server message that says:

```
 1 row(s) affected
 1 row(s) affected
```

in the C# code. Or for example if there is a conflict with primary key, I mean I am trying to insert row with primary key that exists I want to receive the database error message which says : "Primary key duplicate".

Comment: The `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonquery()` function has an `int` return value that already gives you this information. If the query succeeds, you get the number of rows effected. If it fails, such as for the primary key error... well let's just say you'll have no trouble getting that error condition.

Comment: What do you mean by: "you'll have no trouble getting that error condition"?

Comment: If you have an **exception** (a fatal error) from the database - like a primary key violation - then you get all the details in the `Exception.Errors` collection when you catch the exception

Comment: Any error in the query will throw an exception, with the error text in the Message. It's kinda hard to miss those ;)

Comment: These might help:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=344
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37102/Using-InfoMessage-Event-of-SqlConnection-Object

Answer (score 5):

one of the possible solutions:

```
int rowsAffected = 0;
bool HasErrors = false;
try
  {
     SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("some query", "some db connection");
        rowsAffected= sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
     HasErrors=true;
     MessageBox.Show(ex.message)
  }

  if (!HasErrors)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected.ToString() + " row(s) affected.");
  }
```